# Sort two different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How do I sort two different arrays in ascending/descending order in a way where I do not use extra space by using an array/collection? The arrays must be sorted considering the elements in both the arrays.

Consider the example below.

Input:

```
arr1 = {3,1,8,10,9,7};
arr2 = {6,4,5,2};
```

Output:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr2 = [7,8,9,10]
```

Point to note:

- Cannot use extra space (not to create a third array or collection).
- Array size cannot change (arr1 must be 6 sized & arr2 must be 4 sized).

I added all the elements in both the arrays into a List named 'list' as is (unsorted) and then sorted the list in ascending using streams.

```
list = list.stream()
           .sorted((n1, n2) -> n1-n2)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then added the elements in the list back to the array based on their size using below piece of code.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = list.get(i);
}
for(int i=0; i<arr2.length; i++) {
    arr2[i] = list.get(i + arr1.length);
}
```

Comment: Your question is?

Comment: Look up bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

That was not a satisfactory solution.
What could be done:

```
Arrays.sort(arr1);
Arrays.sort(arr2);
```

And then merge both arrays, using `Arrays.binarySearch`, and `System.arraycopy`, and possibly sort one array again.

The joy of that I leave to you.

That solution would have been *in situ*, in-place, without extra memory. The task then also requires some real programming, merging both arrays.

Their requirements maybe did not be covering all, but the *intention* was to have a memory saving ("no extra array").

Comment: Without using the inbuilt sort method.

Comment: That additional requirement just means you have to sort yourself. I cannot imagine they are just checking collections and streams knowledge.

Comment: A sort could be done over both arrays. I do not remember whether some sorting algorithm (bubble sort) would be more suited for not disturbing both arrays' inserts.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use bubble sort, which swaps elements if their relative order is incorrect based on ascending/descending order (being greater or smaller than the adjacent element).

To learn more about bubble sort, go to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/.

Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b;
        // a is size of first array, b is size of second array
        
        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();
        int[] arr1 = new int[a];
        int[] arr2 = new int[b];

        for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
            arr1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i) {
            arr2[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        // Think of a "merged array" sort the "merged array"
        for (int i = 0; i < a + b; ++i) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a + b; ++j) {
                // compare and swap elements into their correct order
                // check if we have to use arr2
                if (i < a && j < a) {
                    if (arr1[i] > arr1[j]) {
                        int temp = arr1[i];
                        arr1[i] = arr1[j];
                        arr1[j] = temp;
                    }
                } else if (i < a && j >= a) {
                    if (arr1[i] > arr2[j - a]) {
                        int temp = arr1[i];
                        arr1[i] = arr2[j - a];
                        arr2[j - a] = temp;
                    }
                } else if (i >= a && j < a) {
                    if (arr2[i - a] > arr1[j]) {
                        int temp = arr2[i - a];
                        arr2[i - a] = arr1[j];
                        arr1[j] = temp;
                    }
                } else if (i >= a && j >= a) {
                    if (arr2[i - a] > arr2[j - a]) {
                        int temp = arr2[i - a];
                        arr2[i - a] = arr2[j - a];
                        arr2[j - a] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Output the sorted arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
            System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i) {
            System.out.print(arr2[i] + " ");
        }
      input.close();
    }
}
```

However, do note that this solution still has some problems:

1. This code is unnecessarily complicated. A better approach will be to merge the arrays first, and then sort the merged array (unless you have restraints on memory).
2. The time complexity of this approach is O(N^2) (because of nested for loops), which might not be a problem for small arrays, but for larger arrays, it could cause the program to run slowly. Another solution can be the relatively faster quicksort algorithm (although the worst case is also O(N^2) Check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/.)